# How do I get all the data in a collection in flutter firestore and display it on the screen?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wrote the following code

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
dynamic books = getData();
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(books.toString()),
    ],
  ),
);
 }
}

getData() async {
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('books').get();

return querySnapshot;
}
```

But the screen shows Instance of 'Future' How can I use the data in the firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data is loaded from Firestore, it won't be available immediately and in fact your `getData` function returns a `Future<QuerySnapshot>`. You'll need to use a `FutureBuilder` object in the UI to handle the asynchronous nature of the data.

Something like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: getData(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator(),
      }else{
        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs
              .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                return Text(data['full_name']), //  field from your document
              })
              .toList()
              .cast(),
      }
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text(snapshot.error!);
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This way:

`dynamic books = await getData();`

Also this will open up other problems, as the `build` method is not `async`.

Use a Controller-Model-View Pattern to avoid these: The controller fetches model (data) and the view displays the model.

Or you use a `StreamBuilder` inside the Widget to show live data from Firebase.